# Can't auto-mount NFS share using fstab

Tags: 14.04, server, fstab, nfs

In Ubuntu 14.04 Server I've got a share mounting correctly with the following command:

```
sudo mount -a 192.168.10.5:/mnt/sf_nas/movies /mnt/movies
```

However, when I add the below line to `/etc/fstab` and reboot, the share is not mounted:

```
192.168.10.5:/mnt/sf_nas/movies /mnt/moviesnfs auto,noatime,nolock,bg,nfsvers=4,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you forget to add a space before `nfs` or is that a typo? And is your NFS server running v4 or v3?

Comment: Yes, the missing space was a typo but it never occurred to me to check the NFS version. The server is a FreeNAS box which, as I just found out, runs version 3.  Changing the version in fstab fixed it.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `nfsvers=4` would cause the mount to fail if your NFS service is version 3. You need to set `nfsvers=3`, or not set it at all (from [`man nfs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/nfs.5.html)):

```
nfsvers=n      The  NFS  protocol  version  number  used to contact the
               server's NFS service.  If the server  does  not  support
               the requested version, the mount request fails.  If this
               option  is  not  specified,  the  client  negotiates   a
               suitable  version  with  the  server,  trying  version 4
               first, version 3 second, and version 2 last.
```