# Mount partition of Ubuntu computer into different Ubuntu computer

Tags: mount, fstab, partitioning, sharing

I have two computers running Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 respectively and both are connected via `TCP/IP`. Right now I am accessing one another via SSH most of the time but I want to permanently mount a certain partition of one computer into the filesystem of the other for convenience.

I tried to facilitate this with an entry in the fstab like this

```
//IP/home/User /media/myfolder cifs auto,uid=1000,vers=1.0,gid=1000, user=username, pass=XXX 0 0
```

but that doesn't seem to work. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount a NFS share in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762471/how-to-mount-a-nfs-share-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Make sure to try this https://askubuntu.com/a/771661/459561 answer so it won't hang at boot if the mount points aren't available.

Comment: its not, since the partition I want to mount is not a NFS but a regular partition on a machine running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: my question is: do I have to make some extra effort in order to prepare the host to be able to share one of is partitions with a client or is a plane ubuntu install enough?

Comment: Options in fstab-lines are separated only by a comma, an additional space is not helpful.`d=1000, user=username, pass=`

Comment: For Ubuntu `nfs` is recommended and I just mount one partition on another machine with `nfs`: `192.168.0.123:/opt on /mnt/storage`

Comment: NFS correctly handles all file attributes, CIFS does not. Did you add & setup the 'server' software on the machine you have acting as server?  You only made mention of change to your client (applies to both nfs & cifs - and I'd too recommend NFS)